# How to resolve the error: "Unfortunately. XXXXX has stopped."

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Good morning,

I have an application in **C#** to develop an application for android (using Xamarin).
The application works normally for android versions 2, 3, 4 and 5. However, using a device with **android 6** (marshmallow), the application loads but crashes randomly displaying the following message on the device screen: **"Unfortunately. XXXXX has stopped."** (XXXXX is the name of my application).

When this message occurs in **Visual Studio** is released the following exception:

> Debugger lost connection to the running application. Likely this means
>   the application terminated unexpectedly.
>
> More details can usually be found in the device's debug log:
>
> http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log
>
> More Details:
>
> Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException: Exceção do
>   tipo 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException' foi acionada.    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.SendReceive(CommandSet command_set,
>   Int32 command, PacketWriter packet)    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Connection.Object_GetInfo(Int64 id)    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.GetObject[T](Int64 id, Int64
>   domain_id, Int64 type_id)    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.VirtualMachine.GetObject[T](Int64 id)    em
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.Event.get_Thread()    em
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleThreadStartEvents(ThreadStartEvent[]
>   events)    em
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet(EventSet es)
>   em Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler()

I've tried to download the API 23, I tried to update the JDK, I tried to update the Xamarin, tried to change the "target" in the file "manifest". But no success.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Already thanks.

Comment: sometimes if the usb cable your device is connected, has a damage, this can happen. try to use a different cable

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `adb logcat` as you replicate the crash?